# How to Merge Two vectors in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, merge

I have three vectors. v1,v2,v3.

```
sort(v1.begin(),v1.end());
sort(v2.begin(),v2.end());
merge(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),v2.end(),v3.begin());
```

Now, after sorting v1, and v2, I want to merge them into v3. 
This is what I have written, but it's getting segmentation fault. Can't figure out why.(if anyone writes solution, please explain why does it work and why my solution doesn't work). I have taken help from [c++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/) . Is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: Use as Output Iterator a `std::back_inserter<>` See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter

Comment: Can it be that your `v3` is too small?

Comment: @Yola , No it can't be. Answer can always be stored in v3. v1 and v2 are not that big.

Comment: So, show us how do you define v1,v2,v3.

Comment: @Yola, it's standard merge sort tree :| .  gst = GenerateSegmentTree. 

so, no problem with space complexity.

Comment: @Yola, it's recursive call in the function given gst...

v1 = x,
v2 = y,
v3 = st[i]

Comment: What is st[i]?.

Comment: @Yola , https://ideone.com/DjS0JG   checkout this link. Trust me, I know when it's MLE(memory limit exceeded) . It's something very different. 

just given an input 5 (array size) , 1 2 3 4 5 (array values) . it gets segFault.

Comment: @schorsch_76 , thanks a lot man. I found solution :) .

Comment: You code just shows that i told you earlier, st[i] is too short, it is zero elements length when you call merge ;)

Comment: Please, **please** always include a **[mcve]**. Without one, we can't know for certain why your code doesn't work, it could be for all sorts of reasons. I've voted to close because it's uncertain what your issue is without a [mcve].

Comment: @Yola , I am still not convinced :| . st[i] is just vector, isn't it ? 

I am passing v3.begin() , means merge v1 and v2, and appened them after v3.begin()... or is there anything wrong ?

Comment: @Tas, cool I will remove extra code.

Comment: yes st[i] is a vector of length 0.

Comment: @Yola , alright, I understood. Before using v3, I need to make sure that it's size is big enough to hold v1, and v2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found an answer from  schorsch_76's comment :) .

```
sort(v1.begin(),v1.end());
sort(v2.begin(),v2.end());
merge(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),v2.end(),back_inserter(v3)); // change here
```

just use `back_inserter(vector_name)`, instead of `vector.begin()`...

Before merging two vectors(v1 and v2) in v3, we need to make sure that v3 has enough size to store both vectors.

Comment: In the example on the above link, we can see that they have specified  size of vector v as 10, while initializing it. So, they can use v.begin.

Comment: In the link, you have `std::vector<int> v(10);` so `v` size is 10, enough to receive the final result. It seems that in your case, you vector is empty.

Comment: got it @OzairKafray

Comment: got it @Jarod42

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `v3.begin()` instead of an inserter, you must guarantee the size of `v3` is big enough to hold all the values from `v1` and `v2`.

Comment: ohh, okay. Now I get it. Thanks a lot :) .